# mod_rewrite not accepting queries in url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

the code below works excellent however if I have a url such as /calgary/dashboard.php?step=change-password PHP won't recognize the $_GET['step']

What can I change here so that I can use $_GET['']

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /city_name

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /city_name/index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^\./]+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/city_name/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/$2.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use QSA,

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /city_name/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/$2.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the query string flag (QSA) to the Rule should fix it, e.g:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/$2.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```